# Model.tt T4 does not generate custom enum files while they have no External Type set

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, t4, ef-database-first

I have a Model.edmx file to which I added a custom Enum type (be it through "convert to enum" or "Add enum type"). Let's call this enum "MyEnum"

I add to this enum some members:

- MyMemberOne
- MyMemberTwo
- MyMemberThree

***Mistakingly, i check `Reference external type` and set it to something, let's say MyExternalEnum, and save the edmx.***

***Then I realize this is not what I want so I edit the enum (Right-click > edit) and uncheck `Reference external type`, click `OK` and save again.***

When I execute the automatically generated Model.tt (Right click > Run custom tool), I expect a file `MyEnum.cs` to be created.

*This is not the case*

Double-checking to see if `Reference external type` is uncheked yields no result.

Why ? What is hapenning ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I peered through Model.edmx in a xml text editor, and saw MyEnum was encoded as such:

```
    <EnumType Name="MyEnum" a:ExternalTypeName="" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/codegeneration" >
      <Member Name="MyMemberOne" />
      <Member Name="MyMemberTwo" />
      <Member Name="MyMemberThree" />
    </EnumType>
```

This *should* be OK because `ExternalTypeName` is empty, but for some reason the Model.tt T4 file generator treats an empty string as a real value, preventing enum code generation from happening.
Removing `a:ExternalTypeName="" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/codegeneration"` from the EnumType tag and saving allows Model.tt to generate the file MyEnum.cs correctly.

```
    <EnumType Name="MyEnum"> <!-- This is ok -->
      <Member Name="MyMemberOne" />
      <Member Name="MyMemberTwo" />
      <Member Name="MyMemberThree" />
    </EnumType>
```

I have seen nothing in the Model.tt hinting to why this behavior exists nor if it is intended (but I highly doubt it...).

I expected somewhere in there to be a `if (ExternalTypeName != null) //Do not generate file`, instead of a `if (ExternalTypeName != null && ExternalTypeName != String.Empty)`, but the actual mistake is not so easy to spot.